# MS-SQL 2008 issues with multiple tables query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need help with writing a SQL query. My tables are:

**Contribution:** 
contribution_id | amount | person_id | currency_type

**Person**
Person_id | firstname | lastname

**related** related_id | person_id | related_personID

**Currency Type** CurrencyTypeID | CurrencyName

There are other tables and fields, but these are the ones I need.

Here is the problem I am having..

When a person contributes the first and last name is easy, but when a Brokerage firm contributes, I need to include the real person first name and last name (not the Brokerage Account).
The Brokerage is on the same table as the person.

So far, i have if the `contribution.currencyType = '12492'` then i need to get the information from related table to find the real person_id.
What I do get when I run the code below is all the data, except when the `currencytype = 12492` then I get null for first and last name. 
Here is my code so far:

`

```
declare @fund int = 165
declare @payment_luid int = 58
DECLARE @report_information TABLE(
                                ContributionID varchar(20),
                                ContributionDate date,
                                firstname varchar(50),
                                lastname varchar(50),
                                memberID varchar(20),
                                Pledge money,
                                cash money,
                                non_cash money,
                                fund_name VARCHAR(50))
 INSERT INTO @report_information
 SELECT c.contribution_id, 
     c.contribution_date, 
     case when c.currency_type = '12492' then t3.first_name else       t1.first_name end,
   case when c.currency_type = '12492' then t3.last_name else t1.last_name end,
   case when c.currency_type = '12492' THEN t3.person_id else c.person_id end as MemberID,
   case when c.currency_type = '12492' then (select amount From  ctrb_pledge where ctrb_pledge.person_id = t3.person_id and fund_id = @fund) else (select amount from ctrb_pledge where ctrb_pledge.person_id = c.person_id and fund_id =@fund) END,
   CASE WHEN C.currency_type_luid NOT IN (SELECT lookup_id FROM core_lookup WHERE lookup_type_id=@payment_luid AND lookup_qualifier2 ='1') THEN CCF.amount ELSE 0 END,
   CASE WHEN CCF.non_cash = 1 OR C.currency_type IN (SELECT lookup_id FROM core_lookup WHERE lookup_type_id=@payment_luid AND lookup_qualifier2 ='1') THEN CCF.amount ELSE 0 END,
   f.fund_name
  FROM contribution as c
 left join core_person as t1
on t1.person_id = c.person_id
left join relationship as t2
on t2.person_id = c.person_id
 left join person as t3
on related_person_id = c.person_id
JOIN ctrb_contribution_fund CCF ON CCF.contribution_id=C.contribution_id
JOIN ctrb_fund F ON F.fund_id = CCF.fund_id
where f.fund_id = @fund
order by contribution_id
SELECT  lastname 
   ,firstname
   ,memberID
   ,coalesce(SUM(pledge),0) as Pledge
   ,SUM(cash) AS cash_gifts
   ,SUM(non_cash) AS non_cash_gifts
   ,SUM(cash + non_cash) as TotalGiving
   ,coalesce(SUM(pledge)-(SUM(cash)+SUM(non_cash)),0) as Balance
   ,fund_name
FROM @report_information
GROUP BY memberid, lastname, firstname, fund_name
ORDER BY lastname asc
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this problem out.  By changing the join statements to FULL JOIN OUTER my missing records appeared.

```
join core_person as cp 
on cp.person_id = c.person_id
full outer join core_relationship as rel 
on rel.person_id = c.person_id
full outer join core_person as newCp 
on rel.related_person_id = newcp.person_id
```

I did change my table to something I can remember. t1 = cp,t2 = rel,t3 = newcp.